# probable water damage to exterior outlet when power-washing house

Tags: electrical

We power-washed our house 2 days ago. We believe water got into one of the exterior outlets which has caused a circuit to trip.  It won't reset. We turned on a fan for several hours yesterday on the outlet, but it still won't work. Any idea how long it should take to dry out, if moisture is what caused the problem?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Also, is the exterior receptacle an ordinary receptacle, or a GFCI?

Comment: If a GFCI outlet that is not stamped WR it is probably toast , prior to the WR type of GFCI outlets being available I find them to regularly fail from normal condensation. WR outlets have the electronics "potted" or encased in a nonconductive material and I have found these to survive moisture when dried out. As Archonosx mentioned below there may be water in the box. I agree that they can hold water and it needs to be dried out.

Answer (score 1):

If it is tripping a circuit breaker you have a lot of water in the box.

If it is a surface mounted bell box, then it can hold a lot of water for a long time.

You should turn the breaker off and remove the cover to drain it. Maybe blow it out with a compressor and allow it to dry out before replacing the cover.

Good luck and be safe!